# Binding a list of text boxes in MVC3 EF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, model-binding

I am displaying a list of editable prices in a table. I looked [at this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) but my situation is a bit different.  The prices have a composite key (made of 3 keys) that uniquely identify them.

How do I identify these text boxes so that the model binder can do its thing?

**Edit:**

My classes look like this:

```
class ParentTable
{
    int ParentTableId {get; set;}
    public virtual List<ParentTable2> ParentTable2List { get; set; }
}

class ParentTable2
{
    int ParentTable2Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Prices {get; set;}
}

class Prices
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ParentTableId { get; set; }
    public ParentTable ParentTable { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ParentTable2Id { get; set; }
    public ParentTable2 ParentTable2 { get; set; }

    decimal costPrice { get; set; }
    decimal listPrice { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

So what show to the user is a list of ParentTable.ParentTable2List 
Each row in the list has the ParentTable2Id, and a text box for costPrice,listPrice etc...

I want the user to be able to type in the values for all the prices, and then submit.

On submit, I don't know how to get each price to get bound to it's associated ParentTable2

Comment: Can we see your code please? Post the structure of your models, and what your views look like

Answer (score 0):

You can still likely use the items shown in phil's posting, no? Simply keep the numbering syntax.

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

    <input type="text" name="[0].Key1" value="Curious George" />
    <input type="text" name="[0].Key2" value="H.A. Rey" />
    <input type="text" name="[0].Key3" value="2/23/1973" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```